# Redux. Export not finish corretly without brackets

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm cannot figure out why the main JS file does not want import the `todo` from `'./actions'` without brackets? The similar situation with `todos` from `'./reducers'` does not have any problems with import.

Main js-file:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import todo from './actions'
import todos from './reducers'

let store = createStore(todos);

store.dispatch(todo('Redux, test!'));

console.log(store.getState());
```

My action file:

```
export const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO';

function todo(text) {
  return {type: ADD_TODO, text}
}

export default todo
```

My reducer file:

```
import { ADD_TODO } from './actions'

function todos(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
            text: action.text
        }
      ]
    default: 
      return state
  }
}

export default todos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is the use of a default and an additional export in your action file.  The `default` keyword is for when you only want to export a single value.  Because you are exporting two things, it makes sense that the bracketed version would work.

Comment: Yes, you are right! It's my fall. Because I does resave my `action` file :)

Thank for you time and help! Cheers!